# Resizing images in GWT and drawing them on canvas

Tags: image, gwt

I looked into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260458/scaling-an-image-in-gwt) but the methods are deprecated and for me doesn't even work. I tried to do something similiar but failed. My sample code:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle{
    @Source("images/castle.png")
    ImageResource castleIcon();
```

And the class that draws the image:

```
private void drawImage() {

        Resources res = GWT.create(Resources.class);
        final Image icon = new Image(res.castleIcon().getSafeUri());
        icon.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                icon.setPixelSize(100, 80);                 
            }
        });

        context.drawImage(createImageElement(icon), x - 65, y - 20);
    }


private ImageElement createImageElement(Image image) {
    return ImageElement.as(image.getElement());
}
```

I've tried [this approach](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5) but it fails to render transparent background

Answer (score 0):

Transparency should work fine with PNG on a canvas. Are you sure your image is really transparent? Maybe your PNG is somehow incompatibly with the canvas implementation. Try a proper 24-bit PNG with alpha transparency...

Comment: It is transparent when I use the different method. I got the feeling that getDataImage somehow lose transparency