# how to create a resizable Image in GWT?

Tags: image, gwt, image-resizing

i want to create a resizeable Image in GWT. I just found a sample for resizeable Panels, see here: http://gwt-ext.com/demo/#resizablePanel .
But it doesn't work for images. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!
Jogi

Comment: Hope that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260458/scaling-an-image-in-gwt

Answer (score 0):

Set image as a background to its container (e.g. your view) with [the following CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609110/responsive-css-background-images/12609315#12609315), and it will resize as necessary.

Comment: okay, that only works when the widgets are not draggable :( I am using gwt-dnd...do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't think that setting a container to draggable will affect this in any way.

Comment: I'm using a HTML-Widget, in my css i set the image as background-image, the property resize:both and overflow:auto. The resizing works! then i add  dragController.makeDraggable(myhtmlwidget), the widget is draggable but no longer resizable! but i wonder, because the resize-symbol is shown.

Answer (score 0):

An image widget is a `<img />` tag in disguise. I find the best way to resize is use css class and set it as a style name with width and height or use inline style using imageWidget.getElement().getStyle().setWidth or setHeight. A percentage width and/or height value could be used in some cases but this depends on the elements display attribute and/or the parent elements available size.

Comment: okay, i created following css: div.resize { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; border: 2px solid; padding: 20px; width: 120px; height:50px; resize: both; overflow: auto; } and then i set: insert2.setStyleName("resize"); but it does not work :( whats wrong?